# Getting invalid date format in Django when date seems to look ok

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my Django program I get the following exception thrown when trying to save to the database:

```js
[u"'2015-09-17 00:00:00' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

The date 2015-09-17 looks ok to me but clearly I am missing something?

The database field is defined like this:

```js
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string which you are receiving contains information about both date and time. But, the field which you are using to save that information in the db is a [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datefield) leading to the error.

**You need to convert the string representation of the received datetime object to a Python [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object.**

This can be done using [`.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) which returns the `datetime` object corresponding to the date string passed to it and the format used to parse it. Then, we can call `.date()` on it to get the date object.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: received_datetime_repr = '2015-09-17 00:00:00' # string representation of datetime object

In [3]: received_datetime = datetime.strptime(received_datetime_repr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # convert to datetime object

In [4]: received_datetime
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 17, 0, 0)

In [5]: my_date_obj = received_datetime.date() # convert to date object

In [6]: my_date_obj
Out[6]: datetime.date(2015, 9, 17) # required value
```

Here, `my_date_obj` is the desired value you want to save in the db.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, is in the time,  00:00:00.
If you remove it, probably works.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make it date only?

Comment: The date is coming in from JSON returned by a url call. I am not sure how useful this is but the table is called movies and the assignment is: movie.date = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['upd_date']. The Django model for the movie table is: date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

Comment: maybe, if you call .date() from this datetimefield, its works.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to save and parse date AND TIME. This is invalid.

You can either user DateTimeField instead of DateField or write custom date formats. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#date-format but I would advise against it - there are issues with localozations.

Simply honour your date format instead of datetime format.

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert the datetime data to date?